# Return name of array which has the highest value

Tags: c++, arrays

Just started studying C++ for a couple weeks now, and been running through some exercises. Though I am stuck on trying to return the array name which is holding the highest number in the array. For example, I made an array for 10 people, for each person I am having them enter the number of pancakes they ate, now I want to return the person who ate the most pancakes. just not sure how to do it. It falls apart at the second if statement.

```
int main()
{

int pancakes[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int max = pancakes[0];
int i;
    int p;

for (int x=0; x<=9; x++)
{
   cout << "Enter number " << endl;
   cin >>  i;
   pancakes[x] = i;

   if(i > max)  
        max = i;
    pancakes[x] = p;

}

cout << endl;
cout  << p << " ate the most pcakes @ " << max << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing some braces around the code under your `if(i > max)` line. Also I think you want `p = x` instead of `pancakes[x] = p`.

Comment: What is it that you want `p` to represent?

Comment: Yes I know about the braces with the if, still doesn't work with them... but I want p to represent the array which is holding the person who ate the most pancakes. so if person 5 who is pancakes[5] entered in 100 pancakes he ate. I want p to represent pancake[5] not the element its holding.

Comment: Here is the exercise I am doing to give you guys a better insight on what im trying to accomplish. 
 Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10)
 Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.

Comment: But Mark, your variable `max` already represents the max pancakes value.

Comment: I think your main confusion is what to store in p.  You should store the array index of the biggest eater.  That is, set p = x whenever you find a new maximum.  In your final output if you want to use 1-based output rather than 0-based indexes, you'll need to output p + 1.

Comment: shoot didn't know you can get negative points just for posting, yikes!!

Comment: Here's a hint: Do you need to know all pancake counts later on? Or do you only need to remember the highest value which was entered? In the latter case, you do not need an array at all.

Comment: @MarkCastilla: btw, I agree that this is a strange downvote. Just guessing, but perhaps someone deemed your last sentence inappropriate for this website.

Comment: Gotcha, edited first post. I'll watch my phrasing from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop and if statement should be as follow. See details and explanation in comments:

```
for (int x=0; x<9; x++) // You need to exclude 9 (do not use <=) because the index start at 0
{
   cout << "Enter number " << endl;
   cin >>  i;
   //pancakes[x] = i; <-- This line and the array is not needed. With this also you actually don't need to 
   //                     store/save what people enter. You just need to keep the max and index

    if(i > max)  // if i (number entered) is bigger than the current max of pancakes
    {
        max = i; // You update the max to the new number entered (i)
        p = x + 1; // you store in p the array index + 1 (your array index start at 0 not 1) 
                   // of the current person who eat the max number of pancakes
    }
}
```

For the initialization:

```
//int pancakes[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; <- The array is not needed. See my comment in above code
int max = 0; // More clean and readable
```

Comment: Still a little confused.. So there is no way to output lets say pancake[5] ate the most pancakes., I can only hold the value of pancake[5] and output it? from what I understand, p is only holding the value of x which is not really pancake[5], I think I just need to read your post a couple of times. Thanks for the quick replies though, you guys rock!

Comment: @MarkCastilla If pancake[5] is the maximum and you set p = x when you discover that (i.e. - inside the if statement that updates max), then p = 5.  When you go to print out who ate the most you can do: cout << "Eater #" << p + 1 << " ate " << max << " pancakes, which was the most!" << endl;

Comment: I see now. I was trying to have it output just pancake[5] by itself like cout << p << ate the most pancakes. But I guess its not possible, which means I would need to do what you described above. Thanks man! Points for everyone !!!

Comment: Your table could be useful if later in your program you need to retrieve/display/modify data for each of your user. But for this simple also, there is no need. If it helped you, please accept the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @MarkCastilla Do not hesitate to accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) Your iteration is wrong. It should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++x)
```

If you use x <= 9 you will actually do 10 iterations of the loop and the last iteration will run off the end of the pancakes array and corrupt memory.

2) When you find a new max, also set p equal to x to remember who had the most pancakes.

3) You initialize max to be pancakes[0].  While that will actually give you the right answer in this instance, you should instead explicitly initialize max = -1 to indicate an invalid maximum when you start.  You also should initialize p = -1 to indicate an invalid eater when you start.  These initializations would allow you to distinguish and handle the case when there is no input too.

4) Optimization: you really don't need an array to remember the # of pancakes each person ate if this is all you are doing.  You can just loop as many times as you want reading input and compare against max.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone, so I do apologize if there is formatting problems.

You say that your code falls apart at your second if-statement yet there is only one if-statement, so I am assuming it is the second line in the if-statement. However, there are two problems with this.

1. You aren't recording the person properly with this: 
   pancakes[x]=p;

This "should be": 
    p=x;

2. You need to put curly braces around the entire statement. For example:

   if (i > max) {
       max= i;
       p=x;
   }